# How to test a Spring @RenderMapping method?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, easymock

I have a Spring method :

```
@RenderMapping
public String gotoPage(RenderRequest argRenderRequest, ModelMap modelMap){
 .....
}
```

How do I test this method - `gotoPage`. Should I use EasyMock/Mockito to mock the `RenderRequest` & `ModelMap` ?

Does the annotation `@RenderMapping` have any impact as part of testing this method ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides an additional JAR with test support classes, called [Spring Test](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).

There is a class as [MockRenderRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/portlet/MockRenderRequest.html). For `ModelMap`, since this class extends a `LinkedHashMap`, I would not mock it but use it directly.

Of course, you could use EasyMock or Mockito to mock both classes, but when Spring provides a mock/test class, I prefer to use this. Most of time, this kind of classes are container/beans and are expensive to mock.

For unit testing this method, I would also not take care of the annotation `@RenderMapping`. My own rule is "unit test the method content, the rest belongs to integration testing".